# Including several xaml files in an xaml (Windows Universal)

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I have two files MyPagePort.xaml and MyPageLand.xaml for portrait and landscape orientations. I also want to have an "integrator" MyPage.xaml,
which uses VisualStateManager for switching between portrait and landscape layout.

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Portrait>
                 include MyPagePort.xaml
            </VisualState> 
            <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                 include MyPageLand.xaml  
            </VisualState> 
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

The trouble is that I can't find a way to include several XAMLs. I just need something similar to "incluide" in Android.

I've found a number of WPF examples of doing that ( or ), but neither appears to work with Windows Universal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best way will be using User Controls, so I can have two user controls for horizontal and vertical layout. One way is to make one visible, another collapse and switch visibility depending on orientation:

```
   <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
     <layouts:MainPagePort x:Name="ContentPortrait" />
     <layouts:MainMenuLand x:Name="ContentLandscape" Visibility="Collapsed" />


   </Grid> 

   <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Portrait"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                        Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPortrait"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                        Storyboard.TargetName="ContentLandscape"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup >
    </VisualStatemanager.VisualStateGroups>
```

However this approach has a significant drawback (and this may be why Stamos didn't recommend supporting two layouts), but there is a way out: if the layout is complex, the unused one will waste space and make it difficult for the application to run (especially on phone). A work around is removing unnecessary layout tree and the one needed:

```
   public async void Window_SizeChanged  (object sender, WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e) 
   {

         ApplicationViewOrientation newOrientation = OrientationUtils.getScreenOrientation();
         if (newOrientation != curOrientation)
          {
              curOrientation = newOrientation;
              setupOrientation();
          }
     }

     private void setupOrientation()
     {
          Panel contentPane = FindName("ContentPanel") as Panel;
          if (contentPane != null) {
             var children = contentPane.Children;
             try
             {
                 children.Remove(children.Where(child => ((Control)child).Name.Equals("ContentChild")).First());
             }


              String layoutPath = "ms-appx:///MainPage" +
                  ((curOrientation == ApplicationViewOrientation.Portrait) ? "Port" : "Land") +
                         ".xaml";
              var newElement = new UserControl();
              Application.LoadComponent(newElement, new Uri(layoutPath),
                          ComponentResourceLocation.Application);
              newElement.Name = "ContentChild";
              children.Add(newElement);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the way you are trying to achieve portrait and landscape orientations is not best practice and its wrong. But if you insist doing it the wrong way you can try using the Frame element.

```
<Frame x:Name="frame" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

and do

```
frame.Navigate(typeof(YourPage));
```

For best practices try (you can also find the integrator there)

- [The two ways to handle orientation in your Windows 8.1 app](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/12/the-two-ways-to-handle-orientation-in.html)
- [Handling VisualState in Windows 8.1 Store apps](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2013/10/16/handling-visualstate-in-windows-8-1-store-apps/)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong about handling two orientations, and I  am doing exactly what was suggested there: using VisualStateManager for switching between orientation, only using Grid will be not quite appropriate in my case. The question was rather technical: how to refer to several XAMLs, given that is is not quite convenient to design both layouts in a single XAML.